Errors messages in big query are truncated for complex errrors
in big query query if I have a complicated query and there's an error, the error message is truncated like this example:
 "message": "Query error: Array element type STRUCT<STRING, TIMESTAMP, STRING, ...> does not coerce to STRUCT<id STRING, createdAt TIMESTAMP, status STRING, ...> at [54:13]",

For this error to be useful I need to see the whole thing!

In what context are you seeing the truncated message?  Is it in the console or returned from an API?  I wonder what we will find if we look in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS for the record of the job that failed.

Can you try Searching it through Cloud logging? Reproduce the error and just track the latest error in BigQuery. (or try using the log explorer:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface)

@Kolban The error is truncated everywhere.

@Nestor also in the logs
